# How to remove the default meta title from functions.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so I have added my own title in the header.php

```
<title>  
  <?php 
    if (!(is_front_page())) {
      wp_title('', true,''); ?>  (<?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>)- 
    <?php }
  echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>  
</title>
```

It works great.

The problem is that when I click on View Source, I see two title codes.

First one is my title that I manually added to header.php

And the second one is the default Wordpress title.

My question is, where do I need to modify (probably in the functions.php?) to remove the default Wordpress title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the following code to your themes' functions.php  to remove the default meta title:**

```
function remove_default_title() {
    return '';
}
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'remove_default_title');
```

I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to use this in your `functions.php` based on: `wp-includes/default-filters.php`

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag' );
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your theme I recommend you remove your custom title from the header, remove the above `remove_action` i previously suggested and use the below solution in your functions.php.  this will hook into the existing theme title and modify its value using your custom title code:

```
add_filter('wp_title', function($default_title){
    $title = '';

    if (!is_front_page()) {
        $title .= wp_title('', false,'') .' '. get_the_time( 'Y/m/d' ) . '- ';
    }

    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    return $title;
});
```

Comment: pasted remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag' ); in the functions.php, but still showing up.. Is there perhaps any other solution?

Comment: What theme are you using? What version of WP?

Comment: Wordpress version: Current version: 5.6.1. Theme: Yoneko.

Comment: Updated my answer after looking at the theme.

Comment: hey mikerojas, for some reason it didn't worked, but I found the solution on my own. Added as an anwser for everyone to use. Thanks a ton for your effort, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working sulution. Just paste the below code to your functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered WordPress overrides `remove_action()` when logged in and viewing the site as admin. If you're still seeing the title tag in your markup even with this set:

`remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );`

...try logging out or viewing your site in incognito.